# Eliminate vertical whitespace between images

Tags: html, css, templates

I am working on e-mail template. Code is something like this :

```html
<table width="702" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" id="template">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<img src="/email/new/top_bar.png" width="702" height="11" alt="" border="0">
<img src="/email/new/bottom_bar.png" width="702" height="11" alt="" border="0">
</td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

I always get vertical whitespace between these two images.

I tried using valign, vspace but no luck. How to get rid of it?

Comment: One question, how you get this two images in one line if there is width of table smaller than images ... If I understand you have problem with vertical white space ???? if images are smaller and fit inside, this problem have solution in answer 1. In your example images are one under the another and there are no vertical whitespace

Comment: U caught me! while typing I misspelled width.....I am correcting it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get whitespace because the images are laid out inline (between two rows of lines there is spacing). You can either lay them out as block elements....

```
img { display:block; }
```

.. or you can use the vertical-align property to define a different vertical align which should remove the spacing...

```
img { vertical-align:top; }
```

http://vidasp.net/media/CSS-vertical-align.gif

BTW, please stop using deprecated attributes (cellpadding, cellspacing, align, border). For each of those attributes there is a CSS alternative which should be used. Also, use some CSS reset code (like Yahoo CSS Reset)...

Comment: @Šime he is building an E-Mail where there still is no way around those attributes, as CSS support is very shaky

Comment: Hey! your answer display:block worked perfect. Thanks! I am working on Email templates and 90% email clients only understand cellpadding, cellspacing, align, border.. they dont know css3 and html5 yet.

Comment: Replacing the HTML attributes with CSS has been around for a long time and it is not related to CSS 3. I don't know much about HTML e-mails, but if you can use the STYLE element to put CSS inside, then you should be able to use the padding, border, text-align, vertical-align and other CSS 2.1 properties... (of course, only if those properties are supported, you have to check)

Comment: True! but most of the Email clients only understand inline CSS and that is very limited properties works. Have a look here : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Oh man. And I thought that cross-browser compatibility for desktop browsers is challenging. Good luck getting uniform presentation in all those clients :)

Comment: Oh man! this is what exactly happened to me as well when I went through this list...For sure cross-browser compatibility seems easier. Thanks for your answer & wishes.. :)

Comment: vertical-align:top; (this works like a charm, thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Strange: This shouldn't be.

Maybe the E-Mail client interprets the line break in between the `<img>`s as white space.

Try setting them directly next to each other: `<img src...><img src...`

Answer (score 1):

Your lines are high enough to accommodate text in the default font, which is higher than your 11 pixel images, hence the gap.

You need to make the lines smaller; the simplest way for your example is to shrink the font:

```
<td style="font-size: 1px;" align="left" valign="top">
```

Tested in IE 8, Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 6.