# White spacing between images that shouldn't be there

Tags: html, css

I'm just messing around with basic HTML and CSS and ran into this problem. I have two images directly on top of each other that appear from the top of the screen and down. I don't understand why there is a white line seperating the two images. I think it's connected to the first image because the second image has the same spacing but smaller, if you highlite the image.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Christdentity</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="logo-banner" src="images/christd_logo_banner.jpg">
        <img class="logo-banner-dark" src="images/christd_logo_banner2.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

img.logo-banner {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 40px; 
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}

img.logo-banner-dark {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/nQe7F/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to the `<img>` as they're [replaced inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) by default

```
img.logo-banner {
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 600px;
height: 40px; 
padding-bottom: 0; 
}

img.logo-banner-dark {
display: block;
width: 100%;
min-width: 600px;
height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQe7F/2/

Also take a look at: [Eliminate vertical whitespace between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854199/eliminate-vertical-whitespace-between-images)

Comment: Those whitespaces are caused by `vertical-align:baseline`, not by whitespaces or carriage returns in the markup.

Comment: Removed that part of my answer - thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Can you put an image on top of an image that has display: block?

Comment: @SethUrquhart: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nQe7F/6/ .. notice I added `vertical-align: bottom;` to the first image

Comment: No that didn't do anything

Comment: I'm trying to put a logo image on top of those two images that serve as a banner for the website.